# How to remove noise from Image in openCV Java

Tags: java, opencv

I am using openCV in Java Netbeans. I have some pictures with lots of noises.Is there any source code for Opencv Java that reduces noise of an Image?

Comment: So isn't a free-code place. Find some tutorial and try it on your own. When you get stuck, come back and ask your question following these guidelines: [ask] and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. OpenCV provides denoising algorithms.

You can find 4 variations presented [here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_photo/py_non_local_means/py_non_local_means.html).

Samples are provided on github [here](https://github.com/Tinker-S/OpenCVSamples).

You may use the OpenCV Library - 2.4.3 has a class you can use org.opencv.photo.Photo which provides the **denoising** methods as in the first link.

The the class documentation is  [here](https://docs.opencv.org/). **Note the link no longer has preview so you will have to download the java html docs and look inside org/photo/Photo.html**

Comment: They are in Python 
Where can I find Java Source Code?

Comment: I didn't understand how do I implement the github source code?
Do I have to include that java file in my project?
@Laurentui L

Comment: Why don't you try actually reading some documention? Introduction to Java Development tells you how to use the opencv library : http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html

Comment: third link is broken:(

Comment: They don't do preview anymore it seems, will update @tdavid